# iOS Typhoon Framework: use parent definition with same selector name causes forever loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, typhoon

I want to use some default assembly with few definitions with few default property injection. This assembly may be like:

```
@implementation AssemblyA

- (UIViewController *)viewController {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[UIViewController class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(title) with:@"TitleA"];
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(output) with:[self presenter]];
        //other injections
    }];
}

- (Presenter *)presenter {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[Presenter class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
         [definition injectProperty:@selector(view) with:[self viewController]];
    }];
}

@end
```

Next I make `AssemblyB` (subclasses from `AssemblyA`) with same definition name and want to change `UIViewController` class (and maybe few new property injections):

```
@implementation AssemblyB

- (UIViewController *)viewController {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[LoginViewController class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        definition.parent = [super viewController];
        //other injections
    }];
}

@end
```

In this case Typhoon framework entered in forever loop.

For resolve this issues I use several solutions:

1. Just rename definition name in `AssemblyB` (For this options all definitions, which use original `-viewController` will be not use new, for example `-[AssemblyA presenter]` will be injected with original `-viewController`);
2. Don't use definition.parent and copy/paste all injection from `-[AssemblyA viewController]` (copy/paste - bad solution)

Maybe you can explain me how best solution for this case, ideally for me - if `definition.parent = [super viewController]` will be work.

Comment: property view is injected with viewController?

Comment: It's ok for VIPER module.